# Display original and updated data of the bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I am trying to modify the following code found on one of the sites to display both the original and updated data in the graph. I want the updated data be in different color and still show the original data and see the change. Can anyone point me the error.

```
<title>d3 example</title> 
<style>

.original{
 fill: rgb(7, 130, 180);
}

.updated{
 fill: rgb(7,200,200);
}

</style>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  // Suppose there is currently one div with id "d3TutoGraphContainer" in the DOM
  // We append a 600x300 empty SVG container in the div
  var chart = d3.select("#d3TutoGraphContainer").append("svg").attr("width", "600").attr("height", "300");

  // Create the bar chart which consists of ten SVG rectangles, one for each piece of data
  var rects = chart.selectAll('rect').data([1 ,4, 5, 6, 24, 8, 12, 1, 1, 20])
                   .enter().append('rect')
                   .attr("stroke", "none")
                   //.attr("fill", "rgb(7, 130, 180)")
                   .attr('class','original')
                   .attr("x", 0)
                   .attr("y", function(d, i) { return 25 * i; } )
                   .attr("width", function(d) { return 20 * d; } )
                   .attr("height", "20");

  // Transition on click managed by jQuery
  rects.on('click', function() {
    // Generate randomly a data set with 10 elements
    var newData = [1,2,3,4];

    //for (var i=0; i<10; i+=1) { newData.push(Math.floor(24 * Math.random())); }

    var newRects = d3.selectAll('rects.original');

    newRects.data(newData)
         .transition().duration(2000).delay(200)
         .attr("width", function(d) { return d * 20; } )
         //.attr("fill", newColor);
         .attr('class','updated');
});
</script>
```

I want to know if I can get control of the original data using **d3.selectAll('rects.original')**

Answer (score 0):

If you select "rects.original" and bind data to it, you create a join with an Update, Exit and Enter selection. Im not sure i fully understand what you are trying to achieve, but if you want new data to be drawn independently of the old rects and data, you have to create a new selection for it:

```
              var newRects = chart.selectAll("rect.new")
                                  .data(newData)
                                  .enter()
                               (...)
```

and draw it.
Beware that overlapping in SVG means that underlying Elements will not be displayed anymore.

Im not sure what you mean by "getting control over the original Data", it is still bound to the selection you bound it to. If you want to modify it, you have to modify the data, rebind it, and then apply a transition on the update selection.